# apache403 forbidden You don't have permission to access

Tags: apache, web-development-server

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin python@v.python.centos
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhost1/documents"
    ServerName v.python.centos
    ServerAlias www.v.python.centos.com

    ErrorLog "logs/v.python.centos-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/v.python.centos-access_log" common

    <Directory /var/www/vhost1/documents>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess v.python.centos processes=1 threads=2 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup v.python.centos

    WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/vhost1/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/vhost1/wsgi-scripts>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /django-tjob /var/www/vhost1/djproject
    <Directory /var/www/vhost1/djproject>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /django-jobs /home/python/djproject
    <Directory /home/python/djproject>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

User: python 
Permission:
/home/python/djproject

```
drwxrwxr-x.  6 python python    4096 Jun 29 14:35 djproject
```

/var/www/vhost1/djproject

```
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4096 Jun 29 14:31 djproject
```

files in "/var/www/vhost1/documents" and "/var/www/vhost1/wsgi-scripts" can access successfully, but "/home/python/djproject" and new folder "/var/www/vhost1/djproject" has 403 forbidden. why?
how to create virtual directory successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the [permissions on a parent folder should be fixed](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19240900759/survive-linux-nix-permissions).

Ie. can't traverse /home or /home/python.

Comment: but, what about "/var/www/vhost1/djproject"? There is an index.html in "/var/www/vhost1/documents" and it works well.

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4096 Jun 29 14:31 djproject-tjob`,what's the meaning of the number "6"? @jpic

Comment: I have solved it. Alias url to wsgi.py.`WSGIScriptAlias /tdjproj /var/www/vhost1/tdjproj/tdjproj/wsgi.py` 
    `<Directory /var/www/vhost1/tdjproj>`
     `Allow from all`
    `</Directory>`
    `<Directory /var/www/vhost1/tdjproj/tdjproj>`
    `Order allow,deny`
    `Allow from all`
    `</Directory>`